executable 'spawner.py' not found on the libexec directory '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager'
I am following the Youtube video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkoGkAd0GYk).
Based on the code from 6:08, I typed the following code:
ros2 launch articubot_one launch_sim.launch.py world:=./src/articubot_one/worlds/obstacles.world

But it returned error message
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/kyle/.ros/log/2024-11-06-00-28-34-226550-kyle-VirtualBox-22558
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executable 'spawner.py' not found on the libexec directory '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager'

Therefore I tried to use the following code to solve:
sudo apt install ros-humble-controller-manager
ros2 run controller_manager spawner.py -h

But it returned the following message:
No executable found

I tried to check what is in /opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager, and the followings are there:
hardware_spawner  ros2_control_node  spawner  unspawner

What should I do to fix my error?

The spawner node in controller_manager is a C++ node not a Python script, which can be called like this:
ros2 run controller_manager spawner <args>

or like this in a .launch.py file:
controller_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["<robot_controller>", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
)


I solve the problem by changing and implementing the following code into launch_sim.launch.py file.
    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
        output="screen"
    )


    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_broad"],
        output="screen"
    )
    delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=spawn_entity,
            on_exit=[diff_drive_spawner],
        )
)

    delayed_joint_broad_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=diff_drive_spawner,
            on_exit=[joint_broad_spawner],
        )
)
return LaunchDescription([
    rsp,
    joystick,
    twist_mux,
    gazebo,
    spawn_entity,
    delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
    delayed_joint_broad_spawner
])

